# Avoid Frequent Locking

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

My program gets lots of data from exchange. The data is parsed into tick object. A typical tick

```
struct Tick
{
    string ID;
    int bidprice[5];
    int askprice[5];
    int totalTradedQuantity;
    int totalTradedVolume;
    .....
    .....
}
```

This tick object is published to network and logged in a file. Currently I am taking a lock for updating the tick and for publishing.

```
Parser Part:
lock();
tick update
unlock();

Publisher Part:
lock();
tick publish;
unlock();
```

As the frequency of data is high (5000 per second) I have to take a lock for each data received. Will it lead to performance issues? How do I avoid taking so many lock. Can anybody suggest a design implementation with minimum locking. Please help.

Comment: I think it needs lock mechanism. I don't see any option to reduce it. IF i am not wrong you are using Mutex Locking mechanism internally.if that is the case , use try-lock feature. It will at-least will not block the thread.

Comment: What exactly does "tick update" and "tick publish" encompass. If all you do is essentially copy already prepared data into a list of some sort, then it won't be bad. If it involves a lot of work, then perhaps you should consider if you can "move" some of the work out of the lock, so only the last steps of "copy the data into the list". Likewise for "tick publish", only lock for the duration when you are fetching data out of the list - once you have a separated data item, you can release the lock.

Comment: The question doesn't have enough information about the update and publish processes.  Do they run in separate processes/threads that share an instance of a Tick?

Comment: An uncontested lock takes about 50 nanoseconds on common hardware, ballpark.  So that's about 0.05% overhead per second.  Where's the beef?  Are you just guessing or have you actually **measured**?

Comment: 5,000 per second is not bad. At 500,000 per second you'd need lock-free data structures.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but why do update and publish run in parallel? Why do you publish while updating, or the other way around? Can't you do all the updates first and the publish them? How many times a second do you need to publish them?

Answer (score 1):

Locking or semaphores are the only tools to prevent race conditions.

Semaphores will prevent busy wait. But locks(specifically spinlocks) will cause a busy wait. (In your case, data frequency is high; you shouldn't worry about busy wait.)

However, there are very efficient and fast locking mechanisms deployed to CPU. In this case you shouldn't worry about lock and unlock overhead.

Moreover, you always have the option to queue the requests and process them in a lock & unlock section.

Comment: Which operating system are you talking of where semaphores busy wait - the four that I know of (Linux (and other flavours of Unix too), Windows, OSE and Symbian) do a proper "let this thread/process wait until the semaphore is free". Only spinlocks busy wait in any of these OS's.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need mutual exclusion, you're going to need to lock.  The best you can do with your current design would be to use unusual locks.  For instance, if you read more than you write, you could use reader/writer locks.  If there's little contention between threads and the same thread will often need the lock several times in a row, you might get a performance boost from biased locks.

However, I suspect that your better bet is a redesign.  My favorite book on the matter is *[Is Parallel Programming Hard, and, If So, What Can You Do About It?](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.html)*.  Every other parallel programming book I've read shows how to make threads communicate (e.g., through locks).  This book shows how to design so that threads can run independently without a need to communicate (and, especially, without a need to coordinate through locks).

Answer (score 1):

Taking a lock is not bad. Lock contention is bad. How many locks do you have? One per tick, one per ID, one in total? Often the simplest solution is to avoid a single centralized lock.